# Find all power of two outputs from an equation

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry, summation

Given the equation

$$f(n) = \frac{2^n}{n+1} \sum_{j=0}^{n}{cos\left( \frac{j \pi}{n+1} \right)^n \left( 
cos \left( \frac{n j \pi}{n+1} \right) + cos \left( \frac{(n - 4) j \pi}{n+1} \right) + cos \left( \frac{(n - 8) j \pi}{n+1} \right)\right)}$$

I want to find all values of $n \ge 4$ where $f(n)$ is a power of two. Through computation I found $n = [4, 5, 10]$ produce $[8, 16, 256]$.

I can guarantee $f(n)$ always produces an natural number for any value of $n \ge 4$. In otherwords $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, f(n) \in \mathbb{N}$.

I can see that $n+1$ must divide all non $2$ factors of the summation, but I'm stuck here.

Comment: f(n) is always rational, but it's not necessarily a natural number.  f(9)=768/5 for example.  Looks like there are powers of 2 at 4,5,6,10,11,12,23 and 47.,Also confirmed 95 and 191. I'm guessing there's always a solution for 2n+1 after that, so there is an infinite number of solutions.